# Копирование данных в new Generation памяти.

Tags: java, jvm

Добрый день!
Разбираюсь с алгоритмом сборщика мусора в new generation области. При заполнении **Eden**'а объекты копируются в область **Survivor1** и **Old**. На основании чего решается скопировать объект туда а не сюда? И еще, на основании чего, объекты из **Survivor1** отправляются в **Survivor2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое представление о работе сборщика мусора (Serial GC) в HotSpot JVM.

При заполнении **Eden** объекты всегда копируются в **Survivor** (Состоит из двух областей *From* и *To*). А пережив несколько сборок в **Survivor**, они копируются в **Old**. Между частями **Survivor** объекты мигрируют при сборке мусора в **Eden**.

Т.е. после каждого заполнения **Eden** области, вызывается сборщик мусора, который собирает выжившие объекты в **Eden** и **Survivor** (*From* space). При этом в **Suvivor space** (*From* space) у каждого объекта увеличивается счетчик (показатель "старости").

Живые объекты из обоих областей копируются в **Survivor** (*To* space). Объекты, счетчик которых перешел определенное пороговое значение, копируются не в **Survivor** (*To* space), a в **Old gen**. Если в **Survivor** (*To* space) не хватает места для всех выживших объектов, "лишняя часть" копируются сразу в **Old gen**.

После процедуры копирования две области **Survivor** меняются местами (*From* и *To*).

Comment: в туториале и в визуализаторе Java visualVM некоторые объекты копируются из **Survivor**(*From* space) сразу в **Old gen** даже если счетчик не перешел пороговое значение(и соответственно не мигрируют). Вот этот тонкий момент не понятен.
PS если я не туплю конечно.

Comment: Почитал маны и обновил ответ. Сборка **Eden** всегда чистит и **Survivor** (*From* space). Если объект сразу попадает в Old gen, значит ему не хватило места в **Survivor** (*To* space)

Comment: все теперь понятно. Хотелось бы выяснить, что курили разработчики этого алгоритма. Алгоритм совсем неочевидный.

Comment: можете дать ссылки на маны, что вы читали

Comment: Да я просто погуглил и почитал. У Ораклов есть пример работы GC http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html